# Jest snapshot testing of FlatList renderItem

Tags: react-native, jestjs, snapshot, react-native-flatlist

I have a wrapper for Flatlist called FlatListShadow but for this post FlatListShadow and FlatList is the same thing

I need to test the renderItem function in FlatListShadow which looks like this

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <Device
        title={item.deviceName}
        platform={item.platform}
        updatedAt={item.updatedAt}
        status={item.status}
        selectDevice={() => selectDevice(item.deviceId)}
        isSelected={selectedDeviceIdList.includes(item.deviceId)}
      />
    )}
```

Unfortuanately in the snapshot it only gives this information

```
renderItem={[Function]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `enzyme` you can achieve it like this

```
// prepare a mock item to render the renderItem with
const mockItem = {
  deviceName: 'mock device name',
  platform: 'mock platform',
  updatedAt: 123,
  status: 'mock status',
  deviceId: '1-2-3-4',
}

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  let shallowWrapper
  beforeAll(() => {
    shallowWraper = shallow(<YourComponent />);
  });

  it('should match the snapshot', () => {
    // will generate snapshot for your component
    expect(shallowWrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  describe('.renderItem', () => {
    let renderItemShallowWrapper;

    beforeAll(() => {
      // find the component whose property is rendered as renderItem={[Function]}
      // if we presume it's imported as ComponentWithRenderItemProp
      // find it and get it's renderItem property 
      RenderItem = shallowWraper.find(ComponentWithRenderItemProp).prop('renderItem');

      // and since it's a component render it as such
      // with mockItem
      renderItemShallowWrapper = shallow(<RenderItem item={mockItem} />);
    });

    it('should match the snapshot', () => {
      // generate snapshot for the renderItem
      expect(renderItemShallowWrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jest :

```
describe('EasyToUseSection', () => {
  it.only('flatlist should return renderItem correctly', () => {
    const itemData = {
      name: 'Name',
      desc: 'Description',
    };
   const { getByTestId } = renderComponent();
   expect(getByTestId('flatlist')).toBeDefined();
   const element = getByTestId('flatlist').props.renderItem(itemData);
   expect(element.props.data).toStrictEqual(itemData);
   expect(element.type).toBe(Device);
   });
});
```

This way the data that is sent is checked and also the component rendered type can be checked